# Link Table to SQL Server table with Identity Increment column

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am in the process of converting my MS Access application to use link tables to SQL Server, and have run into an issue that I need help with. The issue is with one table with a column that was auto increment when it was in Access, and is now Identity Increment in SQL Server. When in Access, the auto increment value appears on the form immediately after entering data into the first field on the form. Now that I am using SQl Server, the number that is generated in the Identity Increment column does not show up on the form after I start entering data. If I scroll backwards to the previous record, and then scroll forward again, I see that the indentity increment is displayed on the form. Does anyone know of a way to get this identity increment value returned immediately to the form when I enter informatiom in the form?

Comment: You cannot get this in SQL Server - the value for the `IDENTITY` column is only determined when the row is **inserted** - not before that.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be updated until the row is inserted into the DB. If you want to see it immediately add:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

Somewhere after you're happy with the input from the user (say, the AfterUpdate of a required field) It will trigger a database insert, and should refresh the form. if it doesn't refresh the form, just add a

```
Me.Refresh
```

in the same place.